# Cubulating non-compact hyperbolic manifolds

Tags: geometric-group-theory, manifolds

> Let $X$ be a hyperbolic manifold of arbitrary dimension. When does $X$ admit a cell structure of a CAT(-1) cube complex? of a hyperbolic CAT(0) cube complex?

I suspect that the question is widely open, but I am rather interested in partial positive results in the non-compact case.